# Vim syntax: Spell checking between certain regions

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a syntax file for this language called Sugar Cube 2.  You can find more about it here: http://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/macros.html

Generally, I don't want to spell check between the macros (e.g., `<<if $myVariable>>`).  But, you can make your own macros, and I happen to have made one that works like this:

```
<<myDescription "This is a string that should be in english">>
```

As you can see, "english" should be capitalized, so it would be useful to have spell checking in that case.

I already know about vim's `syntax`.  It's `keyword`, `match`, `region`, `@NoSpell`, etc.  But I'm really struggling to put these concepts together to achieve what I want:  Spell checking between a specific macro, but not all macros.  Here's my idea, and it leverages the concepts described in `syn-priority`:

```
syn match macroDelimiter "\v(<<|>>)"
" there's much more keywords than this
syn keyword macroKeywords contained if elseif else myDescription
syn region mostMacros matchgroup=macroKeywords start="<<" end=">>" contains=@NoSpell
syn region myMacro matchgroup=macroKeywords start="<<myDescription" end=">>"
```

I mean... I tried that and it works.  One thing I don't like is how `myDescription` is highlighted just like the angled brackets.  I also don't like how the word `myDescription` itself is spell checked, but I can live with that one.  Is there a way to fix these issues?

---

This will fix the above issues:

```
set spell spelllang=en_us
syn match macroDelimiter "\v(<<|>>)"
" there's much more keywords than this
syn keyword macroKeywords contained if elseif else myDescription
syn region macroString start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+
syn region mostMacros matchgroup=macroDelimiter start="<<" end=">>" contains=@NoSpell,macroString
"Notice how this is commented out
"syn region myMacro matchgroup=macroDelimiter start="<<myDescription" end=">>"

hi link macroKeywords Keyword
hi link macroDelimiter Constant
```

But it adds a major problem: There are other macros with Strings.  The `<<link>>` and `<<goto>>` macros have Strings, too.  But I don't want to spell check the strings there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the `matchgroup` highlighting for `myDescription`, but still enforce the match, end the start of the group via `\ze`:

```
syn region myMacro matchgroup=macroKeywords start="<<\zemyDescription" end=">>" contains=@Spell
```

This will enable spelling for `myDescription` itself. To avoid that, you have to turn the syntax for it from `keyword` to `match`, in order to add `contains=@NoSpell` to it:

```
syn match myDescription "myDescription" contains=@NoSpell
syn region myMacro matchgroup=macroKeywords start="<<\zemyDescription" end=">>" contains=@Spell,myDescription
```

Comment: `:help /\ze`. All regular expression help keywords start with `/`. Also interesting for syntax highlighting is the (uglier) alternative `\@=` (positive lookahead, like Perl's `(?=...)`. In contrast to `\ze`, this does not prevent further syntax matches at those positions.

Comment: BTW, is this one of those "many ways to skin a cat" situations?  If there's as much better way to solve this problem, let me know.

Comment: Yes, there are several possibilities to implement a syntax. What's best depends on the exact requirements, as usual. `\ze` looks right here.