# Vim syntax: Spell checking some strings, but not others

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

This is a followup to [Vim syntax: Spell checking between certain regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296273/vim-syntax-spell-checking-between-certain-regions)  I'm trying to create a syntax file for this language called Sugar Cube 2.  You can find more about it here: http://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/macros.html

The [link](http://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/macros.html#macros-link) has this syntax: `<<link "linkText" "passageName">>`  e.g.:

```
<<link "Onward, Reginald!" "ThePassageName">>
```

I would like to spell check that "Onward, Reginald!" but not "ThePassageName".  How do I do that?  I tried messing around with lines like this, but I think I'm going in the wrong direction:

```
syn region noSpellString  start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+ contains=@NoSpell
syn region spellString  start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+ nextgroup=noSpellString
syn match linkMacro "<<link\s+" nextgroup=spellString skipwhite skipempty
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good to me. `:syn region` is the right choice if the strings can span multiple lines. For single-line strings, `:syn match` (with a suitable pattern that skips contained escaped quotes) would be better.

Your example almost works:

- The `linkMacro` pattern needs to use `\s\+` to match.
- the `spellString` is missing the `skipwhite`

```
syn region noSpellString  start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+ contains=@NoSpell
syn region spellString  start=+"+ end=+"+ skip=+\\"+ nextgroup=noSpellString skipwhite
syn match linkMacro "<<link\s\+" nextgroup=spellString skipwhite skipempty
```

For syntax scripts, all syntax groups should start with a prefix that is equal to the syntax name. So, `syntax/sugarcube2.vim` should have syntax names like `sugarcube2LinkMacro`, `sugarcube2SpellString`, etc.

Comment: For some reason, [your previous advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309967/61624) seems to interfere with this advice:  If my synatx file has this line in it, the link text doesn't spell check anything inside `<<link`: `syn region myMacro matchgroup=macroDelimiter start="<<\zemyDescription" end=">>" contains=@Spell,myDescription` . Do you know why that would be?  They seem unrelated to me.  Also, I'd want to to highlight the matching braces between the << and >>.

Comment: FWIW, the `myDescription` line is above the others.

Comment: That should not match anything here, because `myDescription` is missing. I also cannot reproduce it. Do you use the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).) It's really helpful for troubleshooting this!